# Select Previous Day date in EST timezone

Tags: sql, oracle21c

I have the below query where I am trying to fetch rows that only have the previous day as the CREATION_DATE. The Oracle database currently has datetime field saved in UTC time, and I need to change it to EST time for it to be accurate. Oracle stores SYSDATE as datetime (e.g. 2023-06-28T19:29:40.000+00:00) so I am trying to convert it to the MM/DD/YYYY format only, but

```
 SELECT  CAST(CREATION_DATE AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE )
FROM     
 PO_HEADERS_ALL    
WHERE 
  CAST(CREATION_DATE AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE )   >= CAST(SYSDATE-1 AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE )
  AND CAST(CREATION_DATE AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE ) < CAST(SYSDATE AT TIME ZONE '-04:00' AS DATE )
```

This results in the error `ORA-30084: invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier`

How can I change this so that I am capturing both the CREATION_DATE and SYSDATE in EST format, so that this only captures the CREATION_DATE from the Previous day?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CAST as TIMESTAMP` with the `TIME ZONE` outside.

```
SELECT CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL    
WHERE CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' >= CAST(SYSDATE-1 as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
AND CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' < CAST(SYSDATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
```

Although looking at your question:

> I have the below query where I am trying to fetch rows that only have
> the previous day as the CREATION_DATE

Could you not just use:

```
SELECT CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL    
WHERE CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' = CAST(SYSDATE-1 as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
```

Or even (depending on your server time):

```
SELECT CAST(CREATION_DATE as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
FROM PO_HEADERS_ALL    
WHERE CREATION_DATE = SYSDATE-1
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I try to run this: `ORA-30084: invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier`

Comment: If I run a select on the WHERE criteria (CAST(SYSDATE-1 as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') I am getting `2023-06-28T11:33:17.000+00:00`, so it's going back the previous day but it's putting in a specific time (+4 hours ahead of current time), whereas I need the time to start at the very beginning of the day (00:00:00)...I did not think this would be so tricky :)